# Property Wrappers vs Mirroring

Tags: swift, generics, property-wrapper

Happy holidays!

I have a property wrapper that is used to define the key in a key-value pair.

```
@propertyWrapper
final public class KeyValuePair<T> {
    public var wrappedValue: T?
    private(set) var key: String

    public init(key: String) {
        self.key = key
    }
}
```

*EDIT:*
And using the following protocol, to which all KV models should conform...

```
protocol Parametrized {
    var toParameters: [String: Any] { get }
}
```

the property wrapper is used in the following fashion:

```
struct Person: Parametrized {
    @KeyValuePair(key: "first_name") var firstName: String?
    @KeyValuePair(key: "last_name") var lasteName: String?
    @KeyValuePair(key: "age") var age: Int?
    @KeyValuePair(key: "isSingle") var isSingle: Bool?
    @KeyValuePair(key: "isOpenForDating") var isOpenForDating: Bool?
}

var missUniverse2022 = Person()
missUniverse2022.firstName = "Miss"
missUniverse2022.lastName = "Universe"
missUniverse2022.age = 23
missUniverse2022.isSingle = true // Rad <3
missUniverse2022.isOpenForDating = false // Sad :D
```

So, the whole idea is to generate a dictionary of type `[String: Any]` that holds the key-value pairs from that struct using Mirror.
The problem is that the following code is not working (I know why, but I can't figure out the workaround):

```
extension Parametrized {
    var toParameters: [String: Any] {
        var parameters = [String: Any]()
        
        for child in Mirror(reflecting: self).children {
            
/***********************************************
Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred in cast to 'KeyValuePair'
          
Explicitly specify the generic arguments to fix this issue
***********************************************/
            guard let kvPair = child.value as? KeyValuePair else { continue }
            
            parameters[kvPair.key] = kvPair.wrappedValue
        }
        
        return parameters
    }
}
```

So, I turn to the experts here: how to use the mirror logic to get the k-v pairs and put them in a collection?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Because this is used in a networking layer. And some parameters sent to the backend are in a snake-case format, some are capitalized. Also, there are a lot of parameter models like the example. And finally, this is convenient for our Android-turned-iOS developers.

Comment: Oh, I missed a vital part: the mirroring is handled by a protocol that handles the mirroring for all models. I'll edit my question. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Swift community, I got my answer.
https://forums.swift.org/t/property-wrappers-with-generics-vs-mirroring/54325/4

Comment: Try not to include link-only answers. Copy the relevant code which fixed the issue here, in case the link breaks in the future or the user deletes their post. Also makes it easier for users here to find the answer quicker.